# Неатомарные операции С++

Tags: c++, терминология, атомарность

Какие операции называются неатомарными?
Если можно с примером.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Грубо - которые могут оказаться прерванными другим потоком.

Примеры? Ну, например

```
if (a) { f(a); }
```

Пока вы считали `a`, которое равно `true`, и собрались выполнять `f(a)`, другой поток уже сделал `a` равным `false` :)

Или даже такая экзотика - в одном потоке вы присваиваете значение переменной из двух слов. Первое слово записалось, прерывание, другой поток читает из памяти нечто полузаписанное. Работает, записывает что-то свое. Тут снова управление возвращается к первому потоку, и он дописывает вторую половину нашей переменной...

Comment: Быстро и понятно, все в вашем стиле) Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

В C++ атомарными операциями являются лишь операции над `std::atomic`, все остальные операции неатомарны.

При соблюдении определенных условий, на определённой архитектуре, атомарными могут быть операции и над «простыми» объектами, но стандартом C++ это не гарантируется. К примеру, есть у Вас такой код:

```
int64_t var{};
var = -1;
```

Если мы запустим его на 64-х битной архитектуре (amd64, к примеру) то наверняка операция `var = -1` будет атомарной, т.к. шина позволяет записать за один раз все 64 бита, т.е. у нас будет один `mov` в ассемблере. Если же мы соберём этот код для 32-х битного процессора (x86, к примеру), то эта операция перестанет быть атомарной и наверняка будет состоять из двух последовательных `mov`, т.к. за одну *неделимую операцию* нельзя в 32-х битную шину засунуть 64 бита данных.

Правда, в процессорах есть достаточно средств, чтобы превращать несколько операций в одну атомарную, но эти средства будут как раз использоваться с `std::atomic`. Если же средств процессора для реализации `std::atomic` недостаточно, то выходят на более высокий уровень — блокировка мьютексов и прочее. С точки зрения процессора такие операции не могут считаться атомарными, но с точки зрения приложения они будут атомарны, т.к. ни в какой момент времени программа на сможет прочитать частично записанное значение.

Comment: По крайней мере критические данные надо отмечать как  volatile иначе значение в момент переключения процессов может оказаться в регистре общего назначения. Volatile  - сообщает оптимизатору компилятора, что переменную можно хранить только в её памяти, а не кэшировать регистром.

Comment: @PavelGridin, `volatile`, в современном C++ коде, нужно использовать для портов в embedded. Я ему другого применения вообще не вижу, критические данные, которые подвержены конкуренции, должны быть либо под мьютексом либо сами должны быть `std::atomic` — опять `volatile` не нужен.

Comment: @ixSci, а почему на x86_64 вы говорите, что var = -1 "наверняка будет атомарной" т.е. не точно?

Comment: @xperious, мне неизвестно почему такая конструкция может стать не атомарной на вышеупомянутой архитектуре, но я не всё знаю. Т.е. никто не запрещает компилятору переделать этот вызов во всё, что угодно, чего не запрещает стандарт. Я просто сделал подобную оговорку на всякий случай.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще, что атомарно, а что нет надо искать в описании компилятора, для конкретного процессора, например для некоторых DSP присвоение является атомарным, но обычно даже оно не атомарно, для надёжности лучше пользоваться чем то типа std::atomic